# Why can SPRITE measure many simultaneous interactions?

Tags: molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, microscopy, methods

Why is [the SPRITE method](https://www.cell.com/cell/pdf/S0092-8674(18)30636-6.pdf) not limited to a number of simultaneous interactions that can be measured, while microscopy and proximity ligation are limited to 2-3 interactions?

Answer (score 1):

You list three methods for determining the pairwise interactions of DNA loci.

- SPRITE is a split-pool sequencing technique. First, samples are crosslinked to preserve DNA-protein-DNA interactions. Then, DNA is enzymatically digested to create free ends for barcoded adapter ligation. Crosslinked globules are "split" into many wells for barcode ligation, then "pooled" together again in a single tube. After iterative rounds of "splitting" and "pooling", DNA molecules are sequenced. Pieces that are covalently associated by crosslinking will have the same set of barcode sequences, implying that those loci are spatially associated *in situ*.
- Like SPRITE, proximity ligation techniques start with chemical crosslinking and enzymatic cutting to create free DNA ends. In "all-against-all" proximity ligation (Hi-C), free DNA ends are joined together in a dilute ligation reaction. Paired-end sequencing of DNA molecules containing ligation junctions reveals interactions between distal loci. Taking into account [distance-dependent interaction decay](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1046202317302414), the contact frequency of locus pairs can be used to identify potentially meaningful DNA-DNA interactions.
- Microscopy-based methods are limited by spatial resolution and the number of fluorophores (colors) available on a given platform. However, [clever multiplexing](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-020-2983-4) may be able to overcome the fluorophore problem.

In short-read proximity ligation sequencing, it is true that a single DNA molecule can only ligate to one other DNA molecule, whereas SPRITE allows association of a single DNA molecule with one or more other DNA molecules – however many were crosslinked in the same globule. In practice, however, Hi-C is performed on bulk cells, and therefore the same locus may associate with multiple different loci across the contexts of different cells. Moreover, long-read sequencing can capture multiple ligation junctions in a single read, allowing for the inference of primary, secondary, tertiary, *etc*. contacts.